# ionic 2 Module index has not exported member SqlStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am working with ionic 2 and  I have to work with SqlStorage to create queries but it is not imported.

I have this:

import {Storage, SqlStorage} from '@ionic/storage';

But it give me this error:

Typescript Error
Module '"/home/../node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/index"' has no exported member 'SqlStorage'.

My ionic version is this:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

I would try deleting your `node_modules` directory and then run `npm install`

This will rebuild your `node_modules` directory and hopefully work.